# How to use datetime in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, html, android-mediaplayer

I have **android** app as I call **html** files one of these files page for play sound as user can 
 manage when the sound play as:

Saturday  **on**

Sunday    **off**

Monday    **on**

and so on. I did my code well, but when I manage select input
 option values to on and off it return back to its default when I close
 the app or go to another page. So the question is **how can keep with
 select options values for first time as user selected?** Also, if I want
 to play sound in specific time as:

Saturday  on

5.30am  how can I do it?

<play sound method>

```
public class WebAppInterface    {
  Context mContext;
  public  MediaPlayer mp = null;
  public static boolean checked = false;
  /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
  WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
  }


  @JavascriptInterface
    public void playsound(String value  ) {

      if (value.equals("on")){
        checked = true;

        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
      }
      else 
      {  
        checked = false;
        mp.stop();
      }
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
  <form >
    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" onchange="getAzan(this)" >
      <option value="off" >play</option>
      <option value="on">off</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getAzan(sel) {
      var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
      Android.playsound(value); 
    }
  </script>
```

**Note**: I did play sound when user select **on** value at the code up

Comment: will your alarm still be triggered even if the user sets the alarm for weekend and then never open it during the week? I know this is off question but seeing you as new android developer i just want you to remember to keep this too in mind. Happy coding :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it would be better to save those things into `SharedPrefences` instead of storing it on a file.

To use SharedPreferences it's pretty simple. When you get the value (i.e.: `on` or `off`), just open the SharedPreferences, and put those values in it.

```
private void editPlayMonday(boolean shouldIPlay) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("PlayMonday", shouldIPlay).commit();
}
```

Once your values are in place, if you want to know if you have to play a song, just check the SharedPreferences, and look what's in it that way:

```
private void playSong() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean shouldIPlay = prefs.getBoolean("PlayMonday", false);//false being the default value
    if(shouldIPlay) {
        //play song or whatever
    }
}
```

Now, you can have a boolean in your preferences for each days, and just check if these values or on or off for today's date.

I hope it helps!

**EDIT:**
So, up there I gave you the keys to manage your player, and when the sound needs to be played. The `editPlayMonday` function let you register on your application when you need to play your sound, and `playSong` lets you check the preferences to know if you have to play your song.

Now, in your application, you need to use those functions and link them to the javascript. I'll let you do it, I'm pretty sure there is a lot of tutorials and help about that (i.e.: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

The part that I didn't give the details `//play song or whatever`, in the `playSong` functions would be a bit more trickier and you should detail a bit more what you want to do with it. What I would advise you to do is to check out the `AlarmManager` class. It lets you schedule events from your app easily. See  [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for more information or this [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/2651) on how to implement it.

So to summarize, what you need to do with your application:

- Link your HTML switch to the Android `editPlay...` function so that you can register when you need to play a song.
- When you open your webview, check if the SharedPreference corresponding to each days is true or false. This way you can modify the different HTML switch to be on "on" or "off".
- In the `editPlay...` function, and using the AlarmManager, you should schedule an alarm for the next day scheduled, which will link to your song. Remember to check in the SharedPreference if the boolean for the given day is still true. You don't want to play a song the wrong day...

Comment: plz add more details on my code , i cannot reach to what y added

Comment: I edited my answer giving you more details on what you should do now. I  link to the doc and a tutorial that should help you even more on how to play your song on a specific date.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you keep these values in a database? Or if it's only a few settings you want to remember then just save a file locally and read from it upon starting the application every time.

With regards to your timing question, I think this post should help you [Binding MediaPlayer to be played at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001664/binding-mediaplayer-to-be-played-at-a-specific-time) .

**EDIT**

```
   PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("nameTheFile.txt", "UTF-8");
   writer.println(name);
   writer.println(value);
   writer.close();
```

Should write in the file.

Read using:

```
String name;
Boolean value;

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    name=line;
value=Boolean.Parse(line);
}
```

Comment: it is only few settings need to remember when starting , please feedback me with codes. thanks

Comment: I edited my question i added full class codes , please check and edit it with your codes

Answer (score 0):

As described by @MagicMicky you can use `SharedPreferences` to store the values in `onPause()` method

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("Monday", true).commit();
```

and then retrieve the values in `onResume()`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean check_monday=prefs.getBoolean("Monday",false); //false being default value
```

Now your data will be saved even if a user exits the app or move to new `activity`. As far as Alarm is concerned use `AlarmManager` [different example here](http://nerdwin15.com/2013/04/android-creating-an-alarm-with-alarmmanager/) to schedule an alarm by checking `SharedPreferences` for any need for alarm i.e schedule alarm if `check_monday==true`.